# Nothing is showing in my FAQ View

Tags: views, 7

I installed the [Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.drupal.org/project/faq) module and have created questions and answers.

I navigate to /faq-page and all I see if the title of the page "Frequently Asked Questions", but I don't see the actual questions.

I made sure:

1. The content is published
2. Permissions have been set
3. There is a valid 'Views' page

I even tried creating a menu item and that 's not working.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you are missing something in the setup of your FAQ. E.g., if you're using categorized faq nodes, then you also need to do some taxonomy vocabulary setup. Without doing so, you might suffer an issue similar to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1722480#comment-6572990).

Here are some links to Community documentation you may want to verify:

- [FAQ - Basic Setup Guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/244486).
- [FAQ - Settings](https://www.drupal.org/node/144194).

Comment: Yes that 's fixed the issue. I had it set to catagories without their being any. Thanks